# Dynamically add ListView in the code to ScrollView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to add a `ListView` to a `ScrollView` inside the code. But it's not working for some reason. I am new to this. Can somebody help me out?

```
package net.pocketmagic.android.HeaderContentFooterGUI;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/* HeaderContentFooterGUI
 * 
 * Create a sample GUI with a header bar, scroll-able content and a footer
 * 
 * (C) 2011 Radu Motisan, radu.motisan@gmail.com
 * www.pocketmagic.net
 * All rights reserved.
 */

public class HeaderContentFooterGUI extends Activity {

    final static int        idTopLayout = Menu.FIRST + 100,
                            idBack      = Menu.FIRST + 101,
                            idBotLayout = Menu.FIRST + 102;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Hide titlebar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Create our top content holder
        RelativeLayout global_panel = new RelativeLayout (this);
        global_panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        global_panel.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);

        // +++++++++++++ TOP COMPONENT: the header
        RelativeLayout ibMenu = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ibMenu.setId(idTopLayout);
        ibMenu.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line));
        int ibMenuPadding = (int) 6;
        ibMenu.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        global_panel.addView(ibMenu,topParams);
        // textview in ibMenu : card holder
        TextView cTV = new TextView(this);
        cTV.setText("Abirami Mega Mall");
        cTV.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        int nTextH =  18;
        cTV.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTV.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTV = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpcTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        ibMenu.addView(cTV, lpcTV);

        // +++++++++++++ BOTTOM COMPONENT: the footer
        nTextH =  13;
         ibMenuPadding = (int) 15;
        RelativeLayout ibMenuBot = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ibMenuBot.setId(idBotLayout);
        ibMenuBot.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line));
        ibMenuBot.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams botParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        botParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        global_panel.addView(ibMenuBot,botParams);
        // textview in ibMenu : card holder

        TextView cTVBot = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot.setId(5001);
        cTVBot.setText("Home"); 
        cTVBot.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   
        lpcTVBot.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot, lpcTVBot);

        TextView cTVBot2 = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot2.setId(5002);        
        cTVBot2.setText("Booking History");     
        cTVBot2.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot2.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot2.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot2.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
        lpcTVBot2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,cTVBot.getId() );
        lpcTVBot2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);      
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot2, lpcTVBot2);

        TextView cTVBot3 = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot3.setId(5003);        
        cTVBot3.setText("Help?");       
        cTVBot3.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot3.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot3.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot3.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
        lpcTVBot3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,cTVBot2.getId() );
        lpcTVBot3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);      
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot3, lpcTVBot3);      

        TextView cTVBot4 = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot4.setId(5004);        
        cTVBot4.setText("About Us");        
        cTVBot4.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot4.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot4.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot4.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot4= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        lpcTVBot4.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,cTVBot3.getId() );
        lpcTVBot4.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);      
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot4, lpcTVBot4);      


        // +++++++++++++ MIDDLE COMPONENT: all our GUI content
        LinearLayout midLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
        midLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        midLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams midParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        midParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,ibMenuBot.getId());
        midParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,ibMenu.getId());
        global_panel.addView(midLayout,midParams );
        //scroll - so our content will be scrollable between the header and the footer
        ScrollView vscroll = new ScrollView(this);
        vscroll.setId(6004);    
        vscroll.setFillViewport(false);
        midLayout.addView(vscroll);
```

//below code not working ***************

```
            ListView maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(vscroll.getId());
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;     
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("titre", "Movie Ticket");
            map.put("description", "Movie Ticket Booking");
            map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
            listItem.add(map);



            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("titre", "Snow World");
            map.put("description", "SnowWorld Tickets");
            map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
            listItem.add(map);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("titre", "Kissing Car");
            map.put("description", "Kissing Car Tickets");
            map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
            listItem.add(map);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("titre", "Events");
            map.put("description", "Events in Mall");
            map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
            listItem.add(map);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("titre", "Screens");
            map.put("description", "Screens @ Abirami");
            map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
            listItem.add(map);


            SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.main_menu_list,
                   new String[] {"img", "titre", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.titre, R.id.description});


            maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);




        setContentView(global_panel);
    }


}

main_menu_list.xml
------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        android:padding="10px"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"/>
        />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
            android:paddingRight="10px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/titre"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textSize="26px"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In general you shouldn't put a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView` since `ListView`s already scroll.  Now you have nested scrolling objects.

Comment: i have removed scrollview and modiled as below...still not working // +++++++++++++ MIDDLE COMPONENT: all our GUI content
  LinearLayout midLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
  midLayout.setId(6004);
     ListView maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(midLayout.getId());

Answer (score 2):

**Do not add a ListView to a ScrollView** if you don't know exaclty what you are doing.

**Do not add a ListView to a ScrollView** also if you are the best android programmer in the World.

ListViews are not supposed to get in ScrollView. Even if you hack, and i mean big hack, both views by extending them and got them to scroll , also be itemclickable etc etc , **something will break eventually.**
Also do not add a ListView to a ScrollView.

Watch [this](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: This is not true. In some rare cases, such as when needing the entire view to scroll and one sub view is a list while others are things such as webviews, this is necessary. It requires making the listview a defined height, either by specific measurements or through code. I came across a case where this needed to be done and the "hack" was quite small (available in numerous other questions about this), and quite reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You should first get the ListView in you layout using findViewById(android.R.id.list) then you cant add the items into ListView and then add this to scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get reference to the ListView this way. You should execute findViewById(/*Id of the listview element goes here*/).

Edit:

Suppose you have:

```
<ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

You can get access to the listview by:

```
ListView l = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am taking listview refrence this way... still not woking... ListView maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(6004);

Comment: how you can take a numeric value.This is totally wrong buddy. see some example and do some searching it is easy to get this type of stuffs.

Comment: Here is the Complete code...From this code instead of buttons i am trying to add ListView...How can i add...http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1764

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution....here is the complete the code...

```
package net.pocketmagic.android.HeaderContentFooterGUI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HeaderContentFooterGUI extends Activity {

    final static int        idTopLayout = Menu.FIRST + 100,
                            idBack      = Menu.FIRST + 101,
                            idBotLayout = Menu.FIRST + 102;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Hide titlebar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Create our top content holder
        RelativeLayout global_panel = new RelativeLayout (this);
        global_panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        global_panel.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);

        // +++++++++++++ TOP COMPONENT: the header
        RelativeLayout ibMenu = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ibMenu.setId(idTopLayout);
        ibMenu.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line));
        int ibMenuPadding = (int) 6;
        ibMenu.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        topParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        global_panel.addView(ibMenu,topParams);
        // textview in ibMenu : card holder
        TextView cTV = new TextView(this);
        cTV.setText("Abirami Mega Mall");
        cTV.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
        int nTextH =  18;
        cTV.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTV.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.BOLD));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTV = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lpcTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        ibMenu.addView(cTV, lpcTV);

        // +++++++++++++ BOTTOM COMPONENT: the footer
        nTextH =  13;
         ibMenuPadding = (int) 15;
        RelativeLayout ibMenuBot = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ibMenuBot.setId(idBotLayout);
        ibMenuBot.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line));
        ibMenuBot.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams botParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        botParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        global_panel.addView(ibMenuBot,botParams);
        // textview in ibMenu : card holder

        TextView cTVBot = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot.setId(5001);
        cTVBot.setText("Home"); 
        cTVBot.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);   
        lpcTVBot.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot, lpcTVBot);

        TextView cTVBot2 = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot2.setId(5002);        
        cTVBot2.setText("Booking History");     
        cTVBot2.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot2.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot2.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot2.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
        lpcTVBot2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,cTVBot.getId() );
        lpcTVBot2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);      
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot2, lpcTVBot2);

        TextView cTVBot3 = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot3.setId(5003);        
        cTVBot3.setText("Help?");       
        cTVBot3.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot3.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot3.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot3.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
        lpcTVBot3.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,cTVBot2.getId() );
        lpcTVBot3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);      
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot3, lpcTVBot3);      

        TextView cTVBot4 = new TextView(this);
        cTVBot4.setId(5004);        
        cTVBot4.setText("About Us");        
        cTVBot4.setTextColor(Color.rgb(179,116,197));
        cTVBot4.setTextSize(nTextH);
        cTVBot4.setTypeface(Typeface.create("arial", Typeface.NORMAL));
        cTVBot4.setPadding(ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding,ibMenuPadding);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpcTVBot4= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);       
        lpcTVBot4.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,cTVBot3.getId() );
        lpcTVBot4.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);      
        ibMenuBot.addView(cTVBot4, lpcTVBot4);      


        // +++++++++++++ MIDDLE COMPONENT: all our GUI content
        LinearLayout midLayout = new LinearLayout (this);
        midLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        midLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams midParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        midParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE,ibMenuBot.getId());
        midParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,ibMenu.getId());
        global_panel.addView(midLayout,midParams );


        ListView maListViewPerso = new ListView(this);
        maListViewPerso.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;     
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("titre", "Movie Ticket");
        map.put("description", "Movie Ticket Booking");
        map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
        listItem.add(map);


        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("titre", "Snow World");
        map.put("description", "SnowWorld Tickets");
        map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
        listItem.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("titre", "Kissing Car");
        map.put("description", "Kissing Car Tickets");
        map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
        listItem.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("titre", "Events");
        map.put("description", "Events in Mall");
        map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
        listItem.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("titre", "Screens");
        map.put("description", "Screens @ Abirami");
        map.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.reel_icon));
        listItem.add(map);


        SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.main_menu_list,
               new String[] {"img", "titre", "description"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.titre, R.id.description});


        maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);
        midLayout.addView(maListViewPerso);



        setContentView(global_panel);
    }


}
```

Comment: above code for adding Listview to a LinearLayout without layout XML.