# Android: Add Two GridView in each ListView Rows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

In my Application, I have list and Each list items will display two GridViews.
One GridView displays all items with their details, And another one will display some operation regarding to that list.

Is it possible to implement? If yes please provide me the best way to implement ....

Thanks,...

Comment: Check this out . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286900/dynamically-add-listview-in-the-code-to-scrollview/7287963#7287963 .Don't put a vertical scrolling child in a vertical scrolling parent. Same applies for horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I cant add a GridView to the ListView because both of them are Scrollable items.*
Instead i can add a GridLayout there