# Item list in Android like GooglePlay

Tags: android, android-listview, google-play

I'm a beginner in Android development. I'm creating an application where I need to show products as a list with:

- Thumbnail
- Name
- Price
- Rating

I want to make it somewhat like the Apps list in Google play. Can someone direct me to a starting point in making that kind of UI?
I think its something related to `GridView` but, if yes, not sure how to proceed.
Thanks.

**EDIT:** I think people misunderstood my GooglePlay reference. Im pasting an image to show how I want my UI to be.

http://i49.tinypic.com/2cqjqx0.png
(I'm not allowed to post images..)

I already have the tab swipes and everything. Only want to know how this type of list could be created.
Thanks again!

Comment: try to use GridView and using the adapter load the Thumbnail,name,price and rating to your class http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: @sudhanshu you want to create list or grid view

Comment: @Janmejoy `GridView` or `ListView` doesn't really matter which. I just want to know how to implement a GooglePlay like list of apps with 2 columns :)

Comment: @Sudhanshu better you can go for list view as because grid-view does not allow you to list item..k..OR otherwise paste what kind of design you really want

Comment: @Janmejoy I have updated my question with the UI i need.

Comment: @Sudhanshu check the link..if it will not work,let me know

Comment: Why was this question down voted may I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/) and [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) is what you need.
check out the links. They will be useful to you. Its called customize Listview

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already created what you linked. But what I need is to make a grid with 2 items in each row and that list to go infinite. I'm completely clueless about how to do that!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837780/android-set-the-gridview-to-have-2-columns-per-row-only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286900/dynamically-add-listview-in-the-code-to-scrollview/7287963#7287963

Comment: check the links it may be related

Comment: Thanks the first link in the comment gave me a fair idea of how I might try to implement it! Let me try it first though...

Comment: Could you please EDIT your answer to include [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837780/android-set-the-gridview-to-have-2-columns-per-row-only] link? I will accept your answer then.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to create a `custom view` called `layout` for a list  **Item** .

Following code will create a list item of your choice. Modify code as per your requirement. But you can idea from following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Item Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtItemName"
    android:text="Item Price" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Rating"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Just copy and paste above code in your `layout` and switch to `Graphical Layout`. You can see outcome.

Following links helps you how to use `customized layout` in your list view.
[Custom List1](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html) and [Custom List2](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 0):

This two way Android GridView that can be configured to scroll horizontally or vertically.
[This](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview) gridview is what you are looking for.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I looked at it. This utility looks great but it doesnt explain how it implements 2 items in each row and how to go about implementing THAT. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: well,you can review that code.I know there is not much explanation about this,but there is useful comments in the code,so we can read and learn from that.I also wants this kind of functionality in my project and by doing some googling i found this project.Any ways,if my answer useful to you then don't forget to accept it :)